# Automação em HTML [Python]

Tags: html, python, python-3.x

Bom dia, boa tarde e boa noite amigos Devs.

Só deixando claro que sou iniciante --
Tenho duas dúvidas sobre automação dentro de Python.

1- Eu quero fazer um login automático em determinado site, com isso preciso do login e senha do usuário:

```
# Login (CPF)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press('del')
print('Digite seu login (RA ou CPF): ')
login_AVA = input()
pyautogui.press('tab')

# Senha
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press('del')
print('Digite sua senha: ')
senha_AVA = input()
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

No caso, o script para de executar, justamente quando peço a interação do usuário, e em Python não há nenhuma janela (como em outras linguagens) que aparecem as entradas/saídas ?

2- Eu preciso copiar dados de um determinado site, e guardar essas informações para usar em outra página, qual o melhor jeito de fazer isso ?

Exemplificando: No caso da segunda questão, o meu projeto é fazer uma automação para um site de perguntas e respostas da minha faculdade, como base vou usar o Brainly (https://brainly.com.br/) como "Banco de dados".

A idéia é: Copiar a questão dentro do site da faculdade e jogar no Brainly (já consegui fazer isso), e com isso dentro do brainly conseguir a resposta certa, e jogar dentro do ambiente da faculdade marcando a opção correta, e seguindo para outra questão, e assim sucessivamente

Obrigado pela atenção !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo as perguntas:

> 1- No caso, o script para de executar, justamente quando peço a
>   interação do usuário, e em Python não há nenhuma janela (como em
>   outras linguagens) que aparecem as entradas/saídas ?

**R-** Não há.

> 2- Eu preciso copiar dados de um determinado site, e guardar essas
>   informações para usar em outra página, qual o melhor jeito de fazer
>   isso ?

**R-** O melhor jeito é fazer um web scraping, recomendo estudar algumas bibliotecas como a BeautifulSoup para isso

Você pode solicitar a informação antes de interagir com a página, assim:

```
login_AVA = input('Digite seu login (RA ou CPF): ')
senha_AVA = input('Digite sua senha: ')

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press('del')
pyautogui.typewrite(login_AVA)
pyautogui.press('tab')

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press('del')
pyautogui.typewrite(senha_AVA)
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, mas no caso quando eu executo a aplicação com os novos inputs, o meu VSCode fica travado, e não executa nem o (webbrowser.open), a minha pergunta é: como/onde o usuário vai me informar as entradas? Preciso do Tkinter, ou tem algum outro jeito ?

Comment: Não precisa do tkinter, precisa apenas das duas primeiras linhas do código na minha resposta. O input é responsável por gravar a entrada digitada na variável. Quando você executa o script, vai solicitar no terminal as entradas e só vai rodar o resto do código depois de digitá-las.

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, pelo VSCode realmente ele não abre o terminal, consegui obter as entradas pelo Python IDLE